# Anyone here ever brewed Kvass?

Tags: rye, bread

Has anyone here ever made [Kvass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvass)? If so what was the result? How did you go about it? Did you add any special ingredients (spices, herbs, fruit etc...)? Is there any special process I should know about?

I'm going to bake some rye bread tonight so I can brew some tomorrow. And I would love some good info if anyone here has experience fermenting this.

Comment: Don't vote to close. I don't see how this is a subjective question if I am asking how someone else's batch turned out, or any important steps they took. I'm not asking for "The Best Kvass Recipe Ever". I'm asking for advice.

Comment: Do vote to close. As phrased, this question is an open-ended invitation to chat about "x". This is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 2):

I just got the latest issue of BYO in the mail and, lo and behold, one of the stories is about brewing Kvass and Kvass/Beer hybrid brews. I don't know if and when the story will appear online, but the issue should be available in stores soon.

Apparently, East End brewing in Pennsylvania have made a couple of Kvass/Ale hybrids.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I did. I did it many years ago. The main ingredients were:

- [maple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_syrup) and [birch sap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_sap)
- roasted barley
- dried apples

Maple sap is the source of sugar. Maple had to be diluted by birch sap because of first one is too rich on sugar and after some time the kvass might be too richness.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I tried to brew kvass. The results were not good. The product tasted like yeast. Here was my method: 
1. I dried one pound rye bread in oven in a 200 degree oven. The rye bread came from a local bakery that I knew to not use preservatives. 
2. I boiled about a gallon of water for at least 15 minutes to remove any biologicals and whatever chlorine that might have been present. 
3. Poured the water over the bread and let the mixture sit covered for about 10 hours. 
4. Filtered out the bread and added one cup of white sugar and one packet of bread yeast. 
5. I let this mixture sit for about 10 hours covered in a dark closet. 
6. I filtered again added about 2 tablespoons of raisins and let this mixture sit for five days in a dark closet.

The product was milky gold and fairly sweet. There was plenty of sediment, but I don't believe that all the yeast settled out. Anyway, that was my experience.